# For all sets $A$ $B$ and $C$, if $A - B = C$ then $A - C = B$ proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

So I went about drawing

[image]

From looking at the diagram I think the statement is true .
Proof:
Assume $A$, $B$ and $C$ are sets. 
Assume $A - B = C$.
Want to prove $A - B = C$

> I am confused how I am supposed to go about trying to prove this . 
>   So if I want to prove $A-B$ is $C$ then $A$ and $\text{not } B$ is $C$. How do I prove it ?

Comment: Is this assuming $C \subset A$ and $B \subset A$?

Comment: Not necessarily the question did not say  C⊂A and B⊂A

Comment: You *should* be confused, since it is simply not true.

Comment: Your statement is not correct !

Answer (score 2):

Take $A=C=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}$. Then $A\setminus B=A=C$, but $A\setminus C=\emptyset\neq B$

Comment: thanks got it . so the statement was false !

Comment: @MahirShahriar Yes, as a general implication.

Answer (score 0):

First you have:
$$C=A - B = A \cap B^c $$

Then:
$$A-C=A - (A-B) = A \cap (A \cap B^c)^c= A \cap (A^c \cup B)=A \cap B$$

So if you want the equality must happen that:

$$ A-C=B \iff A \cap B =B \iff B \subset A$$

Comment: How do you reconcile your "proof" with @Hellen 's correct counterexample?

Comment: @EthanBolker I'm sorry I'm just showing what must happen to the equality be true.

Comment: The edit does improve the answer.

Comment: @EthanBolker The example does not have $B \subseteq A$ so it is a good counterexample to the *general* statement.

Answer (score 0):

The Venn diagram clearly shows that if $C= A-B$ then $A -C = A \cap B$. This is not equal to $B$ unless when $B \subseteq A$.